# Spawn processes in Fortran

Tags: node.js, fortran, child-process, spawn

How to start a child process in Fortran (such as executing a shell command or so)?

In Node.js, we can use either `spawn` or `exec` to start child processes:

```
var proc = require("child_process").spawn("ls", ["-l"]);
proc.stdout.on("data", function (chunk) {
  console.log(chunk);
});

// or

var proc = require("child_process").exec("ls -l"], function (err, stdout, stderr) {
   ...
});
```

Both of the examples above run `ls -l` (list the files and directories). How can the same thing be achieved in Fortran?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seemed like a "How do you drive in a nail with a socket wrench" type question, but I decided to try a google on it and found

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html

```
      program test_exec
        integer :: i

        call execute_command_line ("external_prog.exe", exitstat=i)
        print *, "Exit status of external_prog.exe was ", i

        call execute_command_line ("reindex_files.exe", wait=.false.)
        print *, "Now reindexing files in the background"

      end program test_exec
```

They've been adding stuff like that to FORTRAN (in the 2008 spec), who knew?

Comment: Is it possible to send the command arguments as different strings? Like a `spawn` equivalent.

Comment: @IonicăBizău The command argument for `execute_command_line` need just be a (default) character (scalar).  In these example they are character literals, but you can use variables or expressions more widely.

Comment: *who knew?*  Lots of people, it's not kept secret.

Comment: The old way was "call system(command)".  Fewer options with this but you may come across it, and some people may not have access to the execute_command_line if they have an older compiler.